# Optimize Pyspark's Collect_List Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I need to aggregate my data so that it generates this output:

**JSON Output**

```
{
    "people": [
       {
         "firstName": "Jimi",
         "lastName": "Hendrix",
         "age": "27"
       },
       {
         "firstName": "Jimmy",
         "lastName": "Page",
         "age": "75"
       }
    ]
}
```

However, when running the aggregate function (below), I get this error:

```
Caused by: org:apache.spark.SparkSession: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of <task_size> task (20GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (20.0 GB)
```

> This leads me to believe that the `collect_list` function is what's causing this problem. Instead of running the tasks in parallel, they run on a single node and run out of memory.

What's the most optimal way to create the JSON output? Are there ways to optimize the `collect_list` function?

**Example code:**

```
def aggregate(df):
    return df.agg(collect_list(struct(
        df.firstName,
        df.lastName,
        df.age
    )).alias('people'))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a collect_list all the data is collected to driver as a list. Instead of this you can create a column in the dataframe with JSON and store it as CSV.

Alternative is to increase the driver memory with -

conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "25g")